# Is it OK when I say "I have a little request from you"? Is it commonly used?

Tags: phrases, grammaticality, prepositions

Is it OK when I say "I have a little request from you"? Is it commonly used?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you mean “a little request **for** you”, because it otherwise doesn't make much sense.

It is understandable, though quite informal. If I want to answer positively, I would typically reply *“Yes, what do you want me to do?”* or, if the context is more formal, *“I'd be happy to help. What can I do?”*.

Answer (score 2):

"Can I ask a small favor of you?" Is a more commonly used phrase, that expresses the same meaning as a request.

Answer (score 1):

If you have received a little request from someone, then saying something like

> I have a little request from you, sat in my inbox. I won't be able to get to it until later, sorry.

is perfectly fine.